# Equal Space in the exam enviroment or other alternative

Tags: exam

I am trying to write a multiple choice exam with the exam package. For each questions I have 6 possible answers (3 in each line). Here is a minimal work example.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\gradetable
\end{center}


\begin{questions}

\titledquestion{\textbf{Multiple Choice}}[10]


What is the capital of the United states?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice NY 
\choice Texas
\choice LA \\\\
\choice San Antonio
\choice Chicago
\CorrectChoice Washington D.C.



\end{oneparchoices}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

I want to have every three answer distributed evenly in one line with equal spaces between them and to have answer a above d and b above e and c above f directly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rely on egreg's code (as most of the times) which he gave me on one of the occasions when I was a victim of similar requirement. Here is a slight modification of his code and I have defined a new environment `myoneparchoices` so that you will have the original `oneparchoices` intact.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{environ,xparse}

%% ------------------egreg's code begins---------------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_undefine:N \choices
\cs_undefine:N \endchoices
\NewEnviron{myoneparchoices}{%
  \par\nopagebreak
  \abd_dochoices:V \BODY
  \par
}
\tl_new:N \l_abd_choices_tl
\seq_new:N \l_abd_choices_seq
\seq_new:N \l_abd_choices_final_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \abd_dochoices:n #1
 {
  \setcounter{choice}{0}
  \tl_set:Nn \l_abd_choices_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_abd_choices_tl { \CorrectChoice } { \choice* }
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_abd_choices_seq { \choice } \l_abd_choices_tl
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_abd_choices_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_abd_choices_final_seq \l_abd_choices_seq
   { \exp_not:n { \makechoice ##1 } }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_abd_choices_final_seq
   {
    \makebox[.3333333333333333333\linewidth][l]{
      \parbox[t]{.3\linewidth}{\raggedright \hangindent1.5em ##1\strut}
    }\hspace{0pt plus .1\linewidth}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \abd_dochoices:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\makechoice}{s}
 {
  \stepcounter{choice}
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\ifprintanswers\CorrectChoice@Emphasis\fi}
  {\normalfont\makebox[1.2em][l]{\IfBooleanT{#1}{\ifprintanswers\CorrectChoice@Emphasis\fi}\Alph{choice}.}}
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\gradetable
\end{center}


\begin{questions}

\titledquestion{\textbf{Multiple Choice}}[10]


What is the capital of the United states?

\begin{myoneparchoices}
\choice NY
\choice Texas
\choice LA
\choice San Antonio
\choice Chicago
\CorrectChoice Washington D.C.
\end{myoneparchoices}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]